# How to create a NPM package that utilizes a web worker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, web-worker, npm-package

I'm trying to create an npm package that utilizes a web worker that is of `type module`. The problem is that the React application I've linked my package to for testing can't find the `worker.js` file. It's looking for it at `http://localhost:3000/worker.js`, but the worker is located inside my package, and my package is locally linked to the React app. How would I go about adding a worker to my npm package?

I tried using WebPack, but that just brought a whole bunch of additional issues to a simple problem of telling my package about this static worker file.

Comment: WebWorker is a browser technology, it doesn't exist in node.js.

Comment: @Barmar Even if that's the case, I still have an issue with letting my npm package know about my static file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I just needed to load the worker by a `URL` object and call `toString()` method.

`new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url).toString(),{ type: "module" })`